# What is the most optimized way of retrieving key and values from a string

Tags: c

What is the most optimized way of retrieving key and values from a string
I have `char *stringRow="thisIsKey1=ThisIsValue1&thisIsKey2=ThisIsValue2"`
I have above string from which I need to extract `char *key` and `char *value`
Which will go in loop until we extract all the key value pairs from the string.

Key and value pairs are divided by `&` character there can be *n* number of key and values in the string. Also, keys and values are of different lengths.

How to do this using simple `C`? Any example would help.

***UPDATE:
I think better way of doing it using `sscanf` parsing. 
can some one tell me how to parse this string using `sscanf` formating.

Comment: Is this a URL query string? You should consider using some standard parser if so.

Comment: Most optimized for what - execution speed, memory consumption, easy maintenance, etc?

Comment: I don't think there's any "optimal" way to do it other than just scanning the string looking for the delimiters.  Perhaps _you_ could code that yourself?

Comment: Can there be keys without values (`key1=&key2=val2` or `key1&key2=val2`)? Can there be values without keys (`key1=val1&=val2` or `key1=val1&val2`)?

Comment: Please find my ***updates in question.

Comment: with sscanf you ahve to know the number of key/value pairs though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First go with Noufals comment.

Otherwise I assume a strtok with "=&" as delimter set should work. And then iterate over the array and build the value pairs.

Be aware though that this does not handle the delimiters included in the key or value values. You need to escape or transcode these.

Comment: Can you suggest me lite HTTP URL parser

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) to split the string easily and build a simple statemachine-like logic to get the key-value pairs (with two states: "reading key", "reading value")